# .editorconfig naming convention not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

I'm trying to create a naming convention for my constants for VS 2017. The problem is that there is some kind of conflict with the rules because I'm getting this error when I define a constant like this:

```
private const string HOLAMUCHACHO = "1";
```

**"First word "HOLAMUCHACHO" must start with a lowercase char".**

This is my .editorconfig:

```
## Private members must be camelCase
dotnet_naming_style.private_field_style.capitalization = camel_case

dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_are_camel_case.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_are_camel_case.symbols = private_field_symbol
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_are_camel_case.style = private_field_style

dotnet_naming_symbols.private_field_symbol.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_field_symbol.applicable_accessibilities = private

## Constants must be UPPER_CASE
dotnet_naming_style.upper_case_style.capitalization = all_upper
dotnet_naming_style.upper_case_style.word_separator = _

dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_upper_case.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_upper_case.symbols = constant_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_upper_case.style = upper_case_style

dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.applicable_accessibilities = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.required_modifiers = const
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the line written before you adding the `.editorconfig`?

Comment: No, I've added the line with the .editorconfig already created. Anyway I post the solution

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so putting const rules above private members seems to work: More specific rules first :)